# How to dynamic list on Card in flutter?

Tags: listview, flutter, dart, dynamic

How to show dynamic list on card widget like below image?

[image]

This dynamic list, want to show :

[image]

The piece of code:

```
Card(
  elevation: 5,
  child: Padding(
   padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top:8.0, left: 8,right:8),
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
       ......

         Flexible(
            child: ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: sample.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index){
                return Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    //data
                    ......
                   Divider(color: Colors.black,),
                  ],
                );
              }
             ),
          )

      ],
    ),
  )
)
```

but showing blank with exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code is a bit long so here is the GitHub repository:

https://github.com/TheKetan2/stackoverflow_answers/blob/master/lib/card_list_example.dart

Output:

[image]

Comment: Oh nice, but one more thing that want to say, these cards are also as dynamic list. can you please set the cards in listviewBuilder.

Comment: Are you saying all the data shown in list should be in Card widget?

Comment: No, I mean, this is one card that you have built  & that is perfect but, want to no of same cards in listview.

Comment: In simple word, wrap this card in ListView.Builder()

Comment: Like this: https://im6.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-6-afc4d402dd61.gif

Comment: Sure, But first i'll check.By the way thank you so much

Comment: Welcome. Happy Coding.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214888/discussion-between-ketan-ramteke-and-shruti-ramnandan-sharma).

Answer (score 0):

With your example shows, I think the only problem is `crossAxisAlignment`.

Please have a test with `CrossAxisAlignment.stretch`.

Or please post your whole code or exception to find the exact cause.